# Magento sort product list by product type

Tags: php, magento

Is it possible to sort the Magento product list by type? Grouped products first, simple products after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a new collection, use `addAttributeToSort()`. For existing collections with preceding sort orders you can use `unshiftOrder()`.

Comment: benmarks, could your elaborate please. I've got     `$_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();` in the list.phtml and I want to display configurable products before simple products. So essentially I want to sort the productCollection before `<?php $i=0; foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>`. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @EasyCo - Please make this a question (a/o/t a comment) and I or someone else will answer :-)